# Hovering on blurred video, how to unblur circle around pointer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

After searching for a long time for an answer, here is my question:

How can I reveal a part of a html5 video that is blurred when I hover on it?

Here is some code:

```
<div id="container">
  <video id="videobcg" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted" volume="0">
  <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

```
#container {
  width: 640px;
  height: 360px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-filter: blur(15px);
  -moz-filter: blur(15px);
  -o-filter: blur(15px);
  -ms-filter: blur(15px);
  filter: blur(15px);
}

#videobcg {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

So, being it blurry, I would like to hover and reveal a circle around the pointer so you can see through the blurred div.

Thanks a lot for your help. If I need to use canvas that is ok, just looking for any answer.

Don't forget it is a video so something like this wouldn't work for me as I need the video being played while the user interacts:

http://codepen.io/jalalazimi/details/tCGbw